# Adding two search box on same page in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new in magento development.I just want to add global search box at two places on same page. kindly find the following link of my [demo site](http://aimaxprovider.in/bishtprice_new/)
in this side if you see when user scroll down sticky header comes up. On that sticky header i want to use same global search box.

Yet i have tried the [following solutions](http://www.snapagency.com/blog/duplicating-magento-catalog-search-anywhere/) but it's still not working.

Comment: i have added following code in header.phtml<div class="sticky_custome_header-search">
  <?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('newSearch')  //echo $this->getChildHtml('stickySearch');  ?>

 </div>

Comment: What is the actual problem/question?

Comment: in my sites home page , i want to display two search box , one is by default search box and other one i want to add it into the fixed header , while user scrolling the site. Currently i m using copy of default search box inside fixed header , but the problem is not working similar just like default one.